# Counting duplicate names in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, counting-sort

I have this csv file (data.csv):

```
data
cn=Clark Kent,ou=users,ou=news,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Peter Parker,ou=News,ou=news,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Mary Jane,ou=News_HQ,ou=news,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Oliver Twist,ou=users,ou=news,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Mary Poppins,ou=Ice Cream,ou=ice cream,dc=company,dc=com
cn=David Tenant,ou=userMger,ou=ice cream,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Pepper Jack,ou=users,ou=store,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Eren Jaeger,ou=Store,ou=store,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Monty Python,ou=users,ou=store,dc=company,dc=com
cn=John Smith,ou=userMger,ou=store,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Anne Potts,ou=Sprinkles_HQ,ou=sprinkles,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Harry Styles,OU=Sprinkles,ou=sprinkles,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=James Bond,ou=Sprinkles_HQ,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
cn=Harry Potter,ou=users,ou=sprinkles,ou=employee,dc=company,dc=com
```

I want a count of how many rows have the same name in `ou`. So for example, if there is `Sprinkles_HQ`, `Sprinkles`, or `sprinkles`, they should count as the same. And if a row has `Sprinkles_HQ` and `sprinkles` (two of the same name), the row should still count as one (not two).

My desired output is this:

```
News, 4
Ice Cream, 2
Store, 4
Sprinkles, 4
```

I have a code that does not work as desired. I'm wondering if someone has a different approach.
I tried using `.pivot_table(columns=[], aggfunc='size')` after I split the the csv contents into columns and made it into a dataframe. Then tried `duplicates.index.get_level_values(0).str.split('=').str[1]` to get my count list, then `duplicates.groupby(level=0).sum()` for my output. My approach was selecting columns, but maybe there's a way to simply check the rows and ignore `ou`'s like users, employees, etc.?

This is the output I have now:

```
Ice Cream    1
News         2
Sprinkles    3
Store        1
userMger     2
users        5
```

---

Possible idea:

```
directory = 'testingOU.csv'

c = ['SPRINKLES', 'NEWS', 'STORE', 'ICE CREAM']

with open(directory, newline='') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
                if c in row:
                        print('True')
                else:
                        print('False')
```

Comment: You can read CSV using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get result. Something like this: `Counter(row[1].removeprefix("OU=").split("_", 1)[0].capitalize() for row in reader)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght would it be possible to use a simple if statement after reading the csv file? such as `for row in csvreader: if 'sprinkles' in row: print(True)` and maybe it'll make it easier to identify a specific string and get a count? I added this code above.

Comment: `for row in csvreader` iterates over file line by line, so if you want to firstly read all file content and work with it after, you need to save it somewhere. I don't clearly get what are you trying to achieve, to be honest.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I'm trying to achieve the desired output I stated above. But, if I can iterate through the rows searching for specific strings, that might look a lot more legible and easier to maintain than a one line code. But I'm trying to see if there are other options.

Comment: I used one-liner to fit it into comment. Ofc you can write the same using regular `for` loop.

Comment: @tripleee you're absolutely right

Comment: I fixed it above now. Quotes should not have been around any of the rows.

Comment: In your data there are several fields called `ou`, but by looking at your desired output i am not able to infere how the counting works. In the code you have tried so far you are checking only for the field at index 1, why?

Comment: @HoxhaAlban Initially, I was only looking at the first OU at the first index of my previous code, but realized in my spreadsheet (bigger than this one), that there were several OUs in the 2nd and 3rd index. Deeming it unusable and I needed a new approach.

Comment: Aww...@NewTechie, why did you delete yourself? I enjoyed your questions... :(